# Curl 7.21 prompt blocklist when trying to connect using sslv3

Tags: curl, openssl, traffic, sslv3, poodle-attack

I am trying to collect traffic about `sslv3` connection, & part of the program using `curl`. To enable `sslv3` connection,
Following are the version list:
 `openssl` **1.02k**
 `curl`  **7.21**
`ubuntu` **14.04**
However, it prompt me "blocklist" when I try to connect. However should resolve this to have a successful connection?

```
zbtest@zbtest-VirtualBox:~$ sudo curl https://orlandofringe.showare.co -3 -k 
blocklist
```

The url was tested with `testssl`, and it is vulnerable to poodle, thus connecting it with `sslv3` should not be an issue

Comment: You _are_ connecting fine; that's the body of the response _from the server_, with HTTP status 403 Forbidden; use `-i` or `-v` to see. Why the server is issuing that response is up to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Establish sslv3 connection, use curl 7.52 on windows 10 with no other pre-requisite. 
As most linux had a latest version of Openssl installed and many other features to ensure eradicate sslv3 connection. It doesn't work on windows server too.